# Reducer is getting called thrice for each routing without performing any action

Tags: react-router, react-redux

I am trying to integrate redux with react-routing. I found a situation like,
i am accessing the same reducer by two component. i am updating the sate from one component, state is getting updated in store. while routing to the another component,again reducer is getting called automatically and intialized the state with default value.
  Here what is happening as per my understanding,reducer is getting called from store and passing the state value as null, so it is taking the default value (feature of ES6) and in same way action.type would null only.

So, My question is why reducer is getting called for every routing even though there is no any user actioned performed. even though if it is calling the reducer, why store is passing null value to the state argument of reducer instead of the state updated by component before routing.

**Reducer:**

```
export const userReducer=function(state={name:"rohit",id:123},action){
    console.log("user reducer called",state);
    switch(action.type){
        case "NEW_USER_REG":                          
                            console.log("user added");
                            state=Object.assign({},action.payload);
                            break;
       case "DELETE_USER":                          
                          consol.log("user deleted");
                          break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

**Component 1(reading and writing from store state):**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar} from '../component/navbar';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div>

                <h1>This is main comp.. below is state got from store</h1>
                 <input type="text" ref="name"/>
                 <button onClick={()=>this.props.register("rajesh")}>update state</button>
                    <hr></hr>
                {this.props.user.name}
        </div>);
    }
}
const stateToprops=(state)=>{
    return {
        user:state.userReducer
    }
}
const dispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
         register:(name)=>{
             console.log("fun called ",name);
             dispatch({
                 type:"NEW_USER_REG",
                 payload:{name:name,id:1}
             })
         }

    }
}
export default connect(stateToprops,dispatchToProps)(Main);
```

**Component 2(reading from store state):**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
export class Second extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, This is active component...</h1>
                <hr></hr>
                {this.props.user.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const stateToProps=(state)=>{
    return{
        user:state.userReducer
    }
}
const dispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
        adduser:(expense)=>{
            dispatch({type:"NEW_USER_REG",payload:expense})
        }
    }
}

export default connect(stateToProps,dispatchToProps)(Second);
```

**Router Component :**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route, Switch
  } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Navbar} from '../component/navbar';
import Second from '../component/second';
import Main from '../component/main';
export class App extends React.Component{
       render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <div style={{height:80,backgroundColor:'#e8e3e4'}}></div>
                    <Navbar/>
                    <div className="text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 60%; padding: 10px;">
                        <div style={{height:5}}></div>

                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-2"> </div>
                                <div className="col-md-8"style={{height:'auto',backgroundColor:'#e8e3e4'}}>
                                    <Router>
                                        <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />                                            
                                        <Route  path='/contact' component={Second}/>                            
                                        </Switch>
                                    </Router>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            );
        }
}
```

**anchor component using  not**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Second} from '../component/second';
export class Navbar extends React.Component{
    render(){

        let styles={width:10};
        return(

                 <div >

                    <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse" >
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">My Learning Project</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li className="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li className="dropdown"><a className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Service<span className="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Get-Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                    </nav>
            </div>
    );
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import {App} from './app'
import {store} from './store.js'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post some snippets of your code like the reducer which is getting called twice and the 2nd component particularly the part where you are dispatching the action. That way we can probably help you.

---

**Solution**

OP was using anchor tags `<a>` to navigate to different urls which were making the page to reload and the redux store to get created again. Switching to `<Link>` solved the issue.

Comment: IMHO, this should be a comment to OP's question, and not an answer, as that's not what it is.

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: How are you hitting those routes, like have put some `<Link>`s or just hitting by entering the url in the browser. I took your code an entered some `<Link>`s to hit those urls and it worked fine.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Actually I don't have enough reputation to comment on the questions.

Comment: @vs1682... i have used <a> instead of <link>. i have added the code for that also. please have a look.
could you please share the working code in plnkr, so that i can figure it out what i am missing. Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding when you click the anchor tag your page gets reloaded and that makes your redux store to get created again. Use `<Link>` instead.

Comment: @vs1682... you are right. exactly same thing was happening. it got fixed after changing <a> to <Link>..... thanks for your help...